# Как получить ключ и его значение из вложенного словаря Python?

Tags: python, массивы

Есть функция, создающая массив, в котором находится словарь. Нужно получить ключ "title" и его значение

Массив:

```py
{'count': 157748, 'items': [{'id': 1094057, 'title': '1 Александровка', 'area': 'Уваровский район', 'region': 'Тамбовская область'}, {'id': 1112583, 'title': '1 Военный', 'area': 'Карабаш город', 'region': 'Челябинская область'}, {'id': 
1086151, 'title': '1 Городок', 'area': 'Хвалынский район', 'region': 'Саратовская область'}
```

Comment: Проходитесь по каждому элементу (словарю) из списка по ключу `'items'` и получаете из этого словаря значение по ключу `'title'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это конечно круто, приводить пример кода с синтаксической ошибкой. Ладно, спишем это на новогодний синдром и нервы по поводу первого поста на сайте. Впредь - будьте внимательны.

```
dic={'count': 157748, 
     'items': [{'id': 1094057, 'title': '1 Александровка', 'area': 'Уваровский район', 'region': 'Тамбовская область'}, 
               {'id': 1112583, 'title': '1 Военный', 'area': 'Карабаш город', 'region': 'Челябинская область'}, 
               {'id': 1086151, 'title': '1 Городок', 'area': 'Хвалынский район', 'region': 'Саратовская область'}]}

lst=[it['title'] for it in dic['items'] ]
lst
```

Результат:

```
['1 Александровка', '1 Военный', '1 Городок']
```

Comment: А где ошибка в этом коде? Просто этот список получен с помощью vk api, он вряд-ли может ошибку допустить.Скорее всего я что-то не так скопировал :)

Comment: @0Hider0 А что, закрывающую квадратную скобку уже отменили?  За решение вашей задачи - можете не благодарить.

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо. Просто список большой, я решил скопировать малую часть и забыл скобку поставить.

Comment: @0Hider0 -  " Спасибо" на этом сайте принято высказывать несколько по другому.

Comment: А как, если не секрет?

Comment: Слева вверху ответа, который вы приняли есть "стрелочка вверх" и есть кнопочка "принять ответ". Вот они для этой цели и используются.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил. Всё равно напишу ещё раз вам спасибо :)