# Как в python из словаря взять нужное мне значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

API присылает мне это:

```
{'meta': {'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T23:59:59Z'}, 
 'data': {'USD': {'code': 'USD', 'value': 1.086766}}}
```

Отсюда мне нужно взять значение value. Подскажите, как это сделать

я пробовал сделать через for, но у меня не получилось

Comment: `resp['data']['USD']['value']` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить ключ и его значение из вложенного словаря Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226210/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще несколько вариантов есть

```
# Способ 1
data = {'meta': {'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T23:59:59Z'}, 'data': {'USD': {'code': 'USD', 'value': 1.086766}}}

value = data['data']['USD']['value']
print(value)

# Способ 2
data = {'meta': {'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T23:59:59Z'}, 'data': {'USD': {'code': 'USD', 'value': 1.086766}}}

value = data.get('data', {}).get('USD', {}).get('value')
print(value)

# Способ 3
from jsonpath_ng import parse

data = {'meta': {'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T23:59:59Z'}, 'data': {'USD': {'code': 'USD', 'value': 1.086766}}}

# Создаем шаблон jsonpath для значения 'value'
jsonpath_expr = parse("$.data.USD.value")

# Применяем шаблон к словарю и извлекаем значение
match = jsonpath_expr.find(data)
value = match[0].value if match else None

print(value)
```